# How to generate deprecated Monero Payment ID

Tags: payment-id

I'm using the monero-gui-win-x64-v0.15.0.2 version wallet.

I understand the usage of Payment IDs is now deprecated, but some miner companies - such as Genesis Mining for example - are still asking for a Monero Wallet + Payment ID. Without a Payment ID no payments are performed.

How is it possible to generate a Payment ID with Monero nowadays?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Old unencrypted payment IDs were deprecated some time ago and support was finally *removed* from the official wallets last release. Therefore, while it's still technically feasible to add an old style payment ID, no wallets will actually recognize it.

Only *encrypted* payment IDs are supported nowadays and these are created by making an integrated address. Alternatively use subaddresses.

If your question is about how to *technically* add a payment ID, knowing nothing will recognize it, this is done by adding the data prefixed with the `TX_EXTRA_NONCE` and `TX_EXTRA_NONCE_PAYMENT_ID` bytes to the tx `extra` field.